# JWT from Auth0 does not seem to work in a fetch() request

Tags: reactjs, jwt, fetch-api, auth0

I am wondering why the JWT i send in a fetch() request does not authorize the request. I tried multiple ways of accessing the JWT (saving it in localstorage and using getAccessTokenSilently()).

```
// Login

import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const LoginButton = () => {
    const { loginWithRedirect, logout, isAuthenticated, getIdTokenClaims } = useAuth0();

    const handleLogin = async () => {
        await loginWithRedirect({
            authorizationParams: {
                prompt: "login"
            }
        })
    }

    const handleLogout = () => {
        logout({ returnTo: window.location.origin });
        localStorage.removeItem('jwt'); // Remove JWT from local storage on logout
    }

    const handleLoginOrOut = async () => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            handleLogout();
        } else {
            await handleLogin();
        }
    }

    const saveTokenToLocalStorage = async () => {
        try {
            const tokenClaims = await getIdTokenClaims();
            localStorage.setItem('jwt', tokenClaims.__raw); // Save JWT to local storage
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error saving token to local storage:", error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <h4
            id="sign-in"
            style={{ fontSize: '1.3em' }}
            onClick={async () => {
                await handleLoginOrOut();
                if (isAuthenticated) {
                    await saveTokenToLocalStorage();
                }
            }}
        >
            {isAuthenticated ? "Log out" : "Log in"}
        </h4>
    );
};

export default LoginButton;

// Trying the fetch()

    const fetchQuestions = async () => {
        try {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt'); // Get access token from local storage
            console.log(token);

            console.log('getAccessTokenSilently():');
            const tokenFromFunction = await getAccessTokenSilently();
            console.log(tokenFromFunction);

            const response = await fetch(baseUrl + 'questions/', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenFromFunction}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to fetch questions');
            }
            const data = await response.json();
            setQuestions(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    };
```

One thing that caugth my attention was that getAccessTokenSilently() returns an invalid signature of the token (checked in jwt.io). Another thing I noticed is that the jwt from the localstorage only contains information about the user (the server expects information about Auth0). How am I supposed to access the JWT successfully?

I tried to save the JWT in the localstorage and getting it using getAccessTokenSilently().

Comment: in `authorizationParams` you need to give the audience as `audience: <YOUR_AUTH0_API_URL>`